# What is the correct eloquent relation for a MySQL Laravel t?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables in MySQL `Apoderados` and `Alumnos` each with their primary identifier id, then I have another table `Apoderado_Alumno` where the id of each table is added, The main idea is that a Proxy can have 1 or more `Alumno` and that 1 `Alumno` can belong to One more `Apoderado`

[image]

I currently have the following relationships in models

**ApoderadoAlumno**

```
public function apoderado()
 {
    return $this->hasOne(Apoderado::class,'id','apoderado_id');
}


public function alumno()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Alumno::class,'id','alumno_id');
}
```

Is it the correct way? I feel no, do I have to add the relationship to the Student and Teacher models?

**Update**

Sorry for the confusion, create the intermediate table because the Alumno may have more than 1 Apoderado (father and mother or other)

Comment: You don't need to make eloquent model for pivot table. Rather you can use many to many relationship. Follow this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @Sohel0415 not even many-to-many, as he described, this looks like a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @HCK he is making relationship on pivot table, i suggested in my comment to use many to many relationship on their parent table/model like alumno/apoderado.

Comment: @Sohel0415 i know. But he says "an attorney can have one or many alumns, but an alumn can only have an attoney. So that's why I go for the option to make a one-to-many relationship. Now, if he has the need of using a pivot table (i can't give you a reason) yeah, he can use the m-m relationship. But it won't be the correct one.

Comment: @HCK got it now, it seems he doesn't need a pivot table, right?

Comment: @Sohel0415 exactly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, if the pivot table is needed, the Alumno can have 1 or 2 or 3 Apoderado.

Comment: @DarkFenix i've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your update.. it means that the relationship between the two models should be a [Many to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

- `Apoderado` **m ----- m** `Alumno`.

## Defining relationships

As you can see in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Relationships are defined in the model. So in:

- `Alumno` model, add the method `apoderados()`:

```
...
    public function apoderados()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Apoderado::class,
            'apoderado_alumno',
            'alumno_id',
            'apoderado_id'
        );
    }
...
```

Now in your `Apoderado` model:

```
...
    public function alumnos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Alumno::class,
            'apoderado_alumno',
            'apoderado_id',
            'alumno_id'
    }
...
```

## In your controller

Then for querying, for example alumnos related to an `apoderado`, you just need to do:

```
$apoderado = Apoderado::find($apoderado_id);
return $apoderado->alumnos; // this will return a collection of alumnos.
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot.